# Sublimetext find and replace using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

In sublimetext2 I need to replace all instances of

```
stream64 = Foo.GetStream64(path64);
```

Incrementing all the occurances of 64 per line like

```
stream64 = Foo.GetStream64(path64);
stream65 = Foo.GetStream65(path65);
stream66 = Foo.GetStream66(path66);
```

without touching the other things, just the numbers. I don't know much a bout regex so how could I make it?

Comment: Regex cannot count, so it's unlikely you will be able to perform the task through them alone. What does your file look like? Are there other things which carry the correct number next to the `stream64`?

Comment: it is so easy with vim's `:s/xxx/\=submatch(0)+1/g` ST should have the same thing, shouldn't it? or just come to vim... :-D

Comment: Regex could be part of the solution. Use your favorite language because you will need a callback. In php for example, you could use `preg_replace_callback()` and set a counter. On the other hand, you might use a parser if it exists for your language to do this

Comment: @Kent ST doesn't have this option unless you write a plugin in python

Comment: @HamZa  It is so **nice** to hear that.. ;-)